# Error: 'ifthrow' isn't a type. ifthrow FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I faced this error, how can I solve it? Flutter

```
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1078:9: Error: 'ifthrow' isn't a type.
        ifthrow FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
        ^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1078:17: Error: Expected ';' after this.
        ifthrow FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1078:29: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '.'.

Try inserting an identifier before '.'.
        ifthrow FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[
                            ^
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

My app was working perfectly and suddenly this error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by upgrading Flutter